# How do I connect bitnami CouchDB with Cloudwatch or Cloudtrail AWS for obtaining audit level logging?

Tags: amazon-web-services, couchdb, amazon-cloudwatch, bitnami, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have made an bitnami couchdb instance and I have configured in the putty. I just want an audit level logs for couchdb such as query should be visible.

How to connect bitnami couchdb with cloudwatch or cloudtrail in AWS? And how to obtain query level logs from them?

I have found some logs in the /opt/bitnami/couchdb/var/log folder where info, error level logs are visible, I want query in the logs file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you CouchDB is running in an EC2. If so, the answer is simple: you need to install the CloudWatch Logs Agent on the EC2.

You can find all the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) on the official AWS documentation

Comment: How do I enable audit level logging in couchDB into the same EC2 instance..

Comment: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/intro.html for configuration intro. You can find the path there. https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/logging.html#log/level for level.